# show .key(keynote) file in iphone

Tags: ios, keynote

I am given some keynote files .

I have to put along with an app .

when I open any app it should show that keynote presentation in the app .

my questions are ,

1. Does ios supports keynote presentation?
2. if yes, how to show them ?

However I checked this out ...

but.. not working

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html

iWork '09 documents do not use a package format and must not be ZIP compressed.

To display supported documents in a UIWebView, create an NSURL as a file URL with the path to the document. Listing 1 demonstrates a method that uses a UIWebView to load a document from your application bundle.

Listing 1  Loading a document into a UIWebView.

```
 -(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
 {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
}

// Calling -loadDocument:inView:
[self loadDocument:@"mydocument.rtfd.zip" inView:self.myWebview];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the keynote file in a UIWEBVIEW as a local bundled file or sitting on a server as well.

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"key"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

you can view Excel (.xls), Keynote(.key.zip), numbers (.numbers.zip), pages (.pages.zip), PDF(.pdf), Powerpoint (.ppt), Word (.doc), Rich text format (.rtf), Rich text format Directory (.rtf.zip), Keynote '09(.key), numbers '09 (.numbers) and pages '09(.pages)

Comment: Hey Zirk... when I tried to put that file in my project of iphone . it showed me the whole folder which is combined of jpg ttf pdf and all other documents . it is not showing me a single file . so when I tried the code of yours , it crashed :(

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: but as i told you ... when I use ppt / pdf file rather then key file , it is working properly ...

Comment: when I drag key file into the project . it is showing the group of files .. can it be the problem?

Comment: try zipping .key file and change  the first line to 

NSString *urlAddress
 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"file.key.zip"];

Comment: it is opening a white page in the simulator and a message is there "error while reading the document"

Comment: check if keynote is saved as Keynote '09

Comment: Hey .. Zirk .. If you dont mind .. can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Hey .. zirk look at the edited question .. still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, or indeed alongside the preview functionality, you can give the user the option to open the keynote using any able and installed applications externally.
There's a good answer to a question requesting this feature here: [How to use "open in..." feature to iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513783/how-to-use-open-in-feature-to-ios-app)