# How to use "open in..." feature to iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm not looking to add my app to the "open in..." list, but to get the list itself. And sending the file to another app.

I'm working on internal communication app, so when user receive a file attachment, s/he can open the file with whatever app is installed on each devices...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile]];
        self.controller.delegate = self;
CGRect navRect = self.view.frame;
[self.controller presentOptionsMenuFromRect:navRect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Implement following `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` methods

```
#pragma mark - UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

//===================================================================
- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self;
}

- (UIView *)documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view;
}

- (CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view.frame;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at UIDocumentInteractionController  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html and here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1

Answer (score 1):

**Another option :**

use `UIActivityViewController` as available from `iOS 6.0 >` version

```
//create instance with file URL
UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[fileURLHere] applicationActivities:nil];
//present it
[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

**Note** : There might be problem using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Check [uidocumentinteractioncontroller-stopped-working-ios-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005087/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-stopped-working-ios-8)