# openvpn ios client custom url scheme

Tags: ios, openvpn, openurl

My application have iOS **[OpenVPN Connect](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/openvpn-connect/id590379981?mt=8)** app dependency.

So I have to check if the app is already installed or not

if so I will just Open the app using OpenURL scheme else I will open its appstore link so that user will install it.

So my problem here is I couldn't find any open url associated with this app.

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

it exports a doctype. so you could use a UIDocumentInteractionController to check if the filetype can be opened and thus the app is installed.

uti is **net.openvpn.formats.ovpn**

copy a file of that type (you can make such a file on OSX) to the bundle and attempt to present an interaction controller for it using **presentOpenInMenuFromRect**

set yourself as delegate and if it fires willShowMenu, then you no the app is there - and you dismiss the menu.

so to get you started something like this:

```
NSString *file = ... //path to file with UTI in question 
UIDocumentInteractionController *c = ... //init with file
c.delegate = self;
_hasAppInstalledForUTI = NO;
[c present...];

if(!_hasAppInstalledForUTI) {
    //act
}
```

...

```
- willPresentOpenInMenu {
    [c dismissAnimated:NO];
    _hasAppInstalledForUTI = YES;
}
```

BTW: I checked the app -- there is no url scheme.

Comment: The solution above will check whether file can be opened or not.I want to check whether openvpn is installed.As I need to open my file only using openvpn app.

Comment: that uti is only used by that app AFAIK ... openvpn config files. as there is no urrl scheme and wont be there without an updated app, this is the closest you'll get

Comment: The willPresentOpenInMenu will be called if the OpenVPN is not installed, it will open the menu with Mail and message options, please see this image http://monosnap.com/image/ja8NsXVGwhxc3QpvNQx5jBGvMgP61m

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it might sound cheeky, I think one way would be to email the developers and ask them if they have a URL scheme, or if they would create support for one.  Its a win-win because their software is more likely to be installed if it can be leveraged in new ways, and you'd get the functionality you need.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of the second half of my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user has the app at all, you would do the following:

```
NSURL *url = "appScheme://"
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
else {
    // can't open url
}
```

But not all apps have url schemes. I know mine don't.

If you are not able to find any online, then chances are there isn't one. Try to contact the developers to find out if there even is one to begin with, otherwise try finding another app that has one, and use that one instead.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have the above code ,I am searching for url scheme for open vpn app

Comment: Well, as I said, they might not have one. Try sending an email to the developers of the open vpn app and ask them.

Comment: @Daij-Djan you're not an answer. This is precisely the answer. Use `openvpn://` and read FAQ https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-ios-faq.html

Comment: Don't insult me. All ok with you? And this was still no answer in 2013. Now i don't know

Answer (score 0):

You try to open an `.ovpn` file.

Here's an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513783/how-to-use-open-in-feature-to-ios-app) from myself to get you started on how to do that.

[Source](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic12055.html).

Though this is not specifically check **that** particular app, but it should do the job.

Comment: 100% what I wrote above just as a link ;)

Comment: I dont want to show open-in using UIDocumentInteractionController, I need to check whether openvpn is installed or not.I need custom url scheme , as I know the implementation

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to open "openvpn ios" application from your application. Please check the below link for same :

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Follow the steps as it said and check whether application is opened or not.

Comment: Napster,I want to check "openvpn ios" is installed or not.I know to check it using url scheme, I want to know the url scheme or any alternate way to achieve the same.

Comment: Karthik: You can check whether application is installed or not with below code :
    NSString *ourPath = [@"appURLSheme://" stringByAppendingString:URLEncodedText];

    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
    if ([ourApplication canOpenURL:ourURL])
        [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
    else 
        NSLog(@"There is no application installed.");

Comment: Napster,I know to check using urlscheme, I am searching for openvpn url scheme,or alternate way to achieve the same.

Comment: you can open with above code. Need to check about alternate if possible. Will update you if I got any solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Support for `openvpn://` URL scheme was introduced in `OpenVPN Connect 1.0.6`, according to OpenVPN Connect [FAQ](https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-ios-faq.html) you can use this code:

```
BOOL installed = [application canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"openvpn://"]];
```

Following code opens `iTunes` to install OpenVPN Connect if it is not installed yet:

```
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
BOOL installed = [app canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"openvpn://"]];
if (installed) {
    [app openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"openvpn://"]];
} else {
    [app openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://itunes.apple.com/app/id590379981?mt=8"]];
}
```

EDITED: actually this approach **DOES NOT** work, I have just tested myself - the matter is that published version of OpenVPN Connect in AppStore is **1.0.5**, so this feature is not available in it ((